Get statistics on FLAC to MP3 (LAME) conversion command
I'm making a simple script in Ruby to convert FLAC to MP3 in batches, sending the decoded FLAC to stdout (to avoid temporary files):
flac.exe -d -c in.flac | lame.exe - out.mp3

In Ruby I can easily run the command with the "system" function or with the pipeline method:
cmd1 = 'flac.exe -d -c in.flac'
cmd2 = 'lame.exe - out.mp3'
process = Open3.pipeline(cmd1, cmd2)

The problem is that, despite converting everything perfectly, during the conversion LAME doesn't show anything on the screen. Only the output of the FLAC decoder is shown, but the LAME histogram along with all its statistics are not shown.
flac 1.4.3
Copyright (C) 2000-2009 Josh Coalson, 2011-2023 Xiph.Org Foundation
flac comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software, and you are
welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type `flac' for details

in.flac: 65% complete

If I set the --silent option to FLAC, it just suppresses the printout, but LAME still doesn't output anything. I read that if you set the output of LAME to '-', it will send everything to stdout:
flac.exe -d -c in.flac | lame.exe - - > out.mp3

But I still can't get LAME's stats to display.
Any help? preferably cross-platform (although I mostly use Windows). Regards.

Questions about command line usage belong on [su]

@greg-449 isn’t this about getting stdout when using Ruby’s Open3.pipeline?

@Stefan They get the output from flac so I would say it something like the lame command suppressing output when in a pipe.
